# Why can't I view my repositories in Subversion?

Tags: windows-server-2008, svn, collabnet

I just installed Subversion (from `CollabNet`) on a Windows 2008 machine.

I created a test repo named, 'test`.

Using `TortoiseSVN`, I can browse to this URL:

`http://dev1-new/svn/test`

But I can not browse to:

`http://dev1-new/svn`

The error I get is:

```
Unable to connect to repository at URL ....
Repository moved temporarily to ....
Please relocate
```

Also notice I'm using `http` and not `svn`.  I can't get anything to work using the `svn` protocol.  So I wonder if there is a firewall blocking it?  If so, what ports do I need to tell IT in order to allow it?

Comment: `svn://` is the svnserve protocol - there's absolutely no reason for you to use it if you've got a working WebDAV setup.

Comment: Well, I'm not really a Windows server guy.  Not sure if WebDAV is setup or not.  All I know is that on our **old** server, we can browse: `svn://dev1/` with TortoiseSVN and get a list of every single repo in the system.  Doing the same with Netbeans also works.  We just want the same ability on the new server.  I'm just not sure what to tell the networking guys they need to unblock.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> But I can not browse to: `http://dev1-new/svn`

Correct, you can't browse a repository that doesn't exist.

> I can't get anything to work using the svn protocol.

Yep, either a firewall issue or you didn't install the service... Couldn't tell which without you filling in the exact details of the installation and doing some troubleshooting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you can successfully browse to http://dev1-new/svn/test, then it's not a firewall issue. All the necessary ports are open, namely 80.

the `/svn` path is mapped to the location of your repositories, e.g., `C:\SVN_repositories`. When you append /test to the URL, the server then looks for the repository `test` on the file system (e.g., `C:\SVN_repositories\test`).

Thus, when you access the url http://dev1-new/svn, it doesn't know which repository to serve to you.

You have two options, both involve changing the Apache configuration:

1. In the `<Location /svn>` section of your config, change `SVNParentPath "C:/SVN_repositories/"` to `SVNPath "C:/SVN_repositories/test"`
2. Add an Apache alias for `/svn` to `/svn/test` so that both URLs work and access the same repository

Comment: Thanks but what I'm trying to do is be able to list ALL repositories in both TortoiseSVN and Netbeans.  On our old server, we would point either to `svn://dev1`.  And we could choose any repo.  On the new server, NOTHING with `svn` works but I **CAN** browse the repos with Chrome using `http://dev1-new/svn`.  But neither Tortoise or Netbeans will browse repos at that http address.

Comment: In that case, it seems Shane Madden's suggestion of SVNListParentPath is the direction you should go.

Answer (score 1):

Configure Apache to show a directory listing for the parent path (this should be in the same location as the `SVNParentPath` directive):

```
SVNListParentPath On
```

I'm not completely sure that Tortoise's browse feature will understand this, but that should allow the listing of all repos in the parent path.